# read credentials from aws by boto 3

Tags: botocore

```
import boto3

from botocore.client import Config

aws_key = config.get('aws_access_key_id')
aws_sec = config.get('aws_secret_access_key')


client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    # Hard coded strings as credentials, not recommended.
    aws_access_key_id=aws_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_sec
)
```

I am getting the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Freedom\Comparing_Files_in_windows.py", line 18, in 
    aws_key = config.get('aws_access_key_id')
NameError: name 'config' is not defined. 
I installed also botocore and still I have this error.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined `config`. I assume that is a configuration file used to store your credentials. However, there are better ways to set your credentials, you can for example use an [AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_profiles.html) or set them as [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html).

Boto3 will automatically pick up these credentials, so no need to explicitly extract them, however, if you require them for backwards compatibility (that is how I stumbled upon this post), you can retrieve these S3 credentials with the `get_credentials` method

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()

credentials = session.get_credentials()
access_key = credentials.access_key
secret_key = credentials.secret_key
```